# How to compare scalars in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, for-loop, comparison, scalar

I have a class called "myClass", which returns "cv::Scalar" type, and I want to do this:

```
cv::Scalar myValue; 
for ( myValue > myClass (i,j) )
....
```

But the comparison part in the "for" line gives out error, saying "no operator > matches these operands". Could someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if cv has anything close to that, but you can define your own freely with the semantics you need.

Comment: The question is how to compare two tuples with 4 values, and it's up to you to define a criteria.

Comment: could you explain it with some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no operator to compare two `cv::Scalar` elements you can define it:

```
#include "OpenCVStuff.h"

// Custom operator to compare cv::Scalar class...
bool operator >(const cv::Scalar &a, const cv::Scalar &b)
{
    bool Result = false;
    // Do whatever you think a Scalar comparison must be.
    return Result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::Scalar myValue; 

    // Assuming myClass (i,j) returns a cv::Scalar
    for ( myValue > myClass (i,j) )
    {
        // Do something...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Doing this you can define the way two `cv::Scalar` are compared without bothering the `cv::Scalar` class itself.

I've put it into the `main.cpp` just as an example, but you can define the operator wherever you want as long it is visible where the comparison is performed.

Answer (score 6):

In order to complete Zhi Lu's answer:

If you want to compare an element of Scalar, you should do next:

```
cv::Scalar scalar(myValue);   //here you assign a value to the element (0,0)
for (scalar.val[0,0] > myClass (i,j)) // access the elment of Scalar
{
}
```

Anyway there is no point on using Scalar if you just want a single value. And also note that you need a proper for loop expression like

```
for(i = 0; i < 0; i++){}
```

Comment: I think you meant `scalar.val[0]`.

Answer (score 5):

Scalar is a four-double-type-element array. You can either store any number of elements (double type) in such structure. So, you cannot compare one instance of Scalar with another directly like that of int type.